# How to instantiate an object in an Activity and wait for it to finish loading

Tags: java, android

I have an activity DisplayResults that gets started from my `MainActivity`. In the `DisplayResultsActivity`, it creates an object of a custom class ProductFinder in its `onCreate()` function. In ProductFinder's constructor, there is a `while` loop that takes about 10 seconds to execute.

My problem is that when I start `DisplayResult` from `MainActivity`, the whole screen goes black for the duration of the while loop, then finally the `DisplayResults` activity shows on the screen with everything.

What I would like is to draw the `DisplayResults` activity normally, then wait for the loop in the `ProductFinder` class to finish what it's doing without having the entire UI freeze. Having a loading circle in the middle of `DisplayResults` while the loop is running would be nice.

What is the proper method of doing this? I know that something needs to go in a thread, but I'm not sure which class to put the loading circle in and which code to put inside the thread.

Comment: You have to use a AsyncTask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: you can `AsyncTask` for while loop OR use a Background thread and show a progress bar until the process is finished.

Comment: Consider using `RxAndroid` for these kinds of work.

Answer (score 0):

It is all depends on the requirements

As stated, you can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) to do the job but you might get issues such as memory leaks and handling configuration changes(e.g. device rotation).

Second option would be to use [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader) which will let you handle configuration changes ([Difference between AsyncTask to AsyncTaskLoader by Google](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%203/71c_asynctask_and_asynctaskloader_md.html)).

Third option, and newer approach, would be to subscribe to ViewModel with  [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#create_livedata_objects) attached to the activity with a background thread to pass the states values (you can also use AsyncTask to manage the states)

Last option (maybe the first) would be to use [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)